# dynamic module does not define init function with python 2.2 only

Tags: python, c++, cpython, python-c-api, python-2.2

I have a problem with the dynamic error `module does not define init function (initsomething)`.
Everything is fine when I use python 2.7, the problem only occurs with compilation using python 2.2
The output format is .pyd.
My code in c++

```
#ifndef PyMODINIT_FUNC
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC void
#endif

extern "C" PyMODINIT_FUNC initsomething(void)
{
    (void)Py_InitModule("something", methods);
}
```

Comment: python2.2? That must be a leftover of the time machine theme.

Comment: I've replaced the Cython tag for a CPython tag. They aren't the same thing...